# EPSG:4326 vs EPSG:3857 - Why are they aligned?

Tags: coordinate-system

Firstly I'd like to point out that I am a very basic user and trying to get my head around a few things.

I have a KML boundary saved from Google Earth. I can then drop this boundary in to QGIS which shows up with CRS of EPSG:4326. I can then open the Google satellite imagery and this confirms that my boundary is in the correct position.

So now I have 2 layers, my boundary in EPSG:4326 and the Google Satellite which shows CRS EPSG:3857.

How are they aligned perfectly if they are on a different CRS?

Comment: They aren't, but they're drawn that way (because they have correct metadata). This is the contrapositive of the usual new-to-projections question "If I change the metadata to lie about the actual projection so they're the same, why don't they don't align anymore?"

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#basic-fa-on-the-fly-reprojection):

> By default, QGIS reprojects data “on the fly”. What this means is that
> even if the data itself is in another CRS, QGIS can project it as if
> it were in a CRS of your choice.